# Rename Chat room

Tags: discussion, chat

A quick suggestion to possibly rename the chatroom to something like "stackexchange photo chat".

I think having one chat room called "photographic memories" may put people off visiting if they think their questions are general photography and unrelated to 'memories'.

Comment: i am so happy that someone finally brought this up. i always thought it, but never thought of bringing it up!

Comment: how do we go about changing the name? and what is the name we should use. "stackexchange photo chat" is a little dry...

Comment: It already was changed...

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, throw me in with the initially confused. And then I was like .... oohhhh, it's a pun, I get it. But still.

My vote is for renaming it "Photography".

Comment: Agreed. I don't think it has to have a clever name. That being said, if someone comes up with an awesomely clever name that is still really clear about the subject, I wouldn't object. :)

Answer (score 5):

Completely agree.  Confused the heck out of me too at first.  Maybe something *slightly* more clever than just se photo chat - but definitely needs to be more obvious.

Comment: But what to go for instead? There are all the clihcés around Darkroom Discussions,  but that's not very inclusive

Answer (score 2):

The Dark Room was suggested in chat, I like that idea.

Comment: I can already see the "take it to chat" messages that would lead to: "Take it to The Dark Room and see what develops..." ;)

Comment: I also like the idea, BUT I think it bring up the same issues with confusion that the previous name had. So do I ask questions about digital photography in the "dark room" or just questions about "film developing"? I think the main chat page design adds to the confusion, and doesn't allow a quirky name without causing this issue.