# Should we revisit the name of our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

I'm participating in a private beta for Pets and the chat room name came up. My suggestion of "The Litter Box" seems to have won the day (for now) because it's a quirky take on the idea of chat being  the place to "go" when it's not appropriate for the main site. That got me thinking that our chat room title is, well, a little dull...

So, what do people think? Keep it as is? Suggest something new? Am I insane? (I may be)

Comment: The Litter Box does seem like an odd choice though since that's where the poop goes.  "The Cutting Room Floor"?

Comment: Or maybe "The Darkroom", as "Cutting Room" seems more of a video related thing.

Comment: @jrista - I like "The Darkroom"

Comment: I updated it... Let's see who notices. :D

Comment: So much for stealth, forgot it announced it...

Comment: If we ever want to change it again, how about The Mirror Box? Although that maybe a bit exclusionary towards the mirrorless.

Comment: As a near copy/paste argument from other users: a chat room with the name _"The Mirror Box"_ would be a place to talk about mirror box related issues only. I don't really accept this argument, but nevertheless it was given to _"The Darkroom"_ name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this has already been done(the chat is now "The Darkroom").

I will throw in my two cents though. I'm not a fan of quirky chat room names. I think it is confusing and it was for me when I first started using this website. At that time our chat room was named "Photographic Memories". Which I wasn't sure if it was for some specific type of chatting or the general chat.

At the end of 2011, [it was decided](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/rename-chat-room) to change the chat room from "Photographic Memories" to "Photography". This cleared up any confusion about what the chat room was for.

I vote that the chat room be named: **Photography Chat**

Comment: I was going to write this, but +1 instead. Cutesy names may be fun for a few minutes for the "in" crowd, but are annoying and off-putting, especially for newcomers. These kind of names say *"If you're not one of the initiated few, you don't belong here"*. They can also be just plain misleading. *Photographic Memories* doesn't sound like a general photography chat room to me, and I think other people woule be confused too.  *The Darkroom* is even more misleading.  Bad idea, since I think the intent is to include more than just darkroom-related issues, which are rare now in the digital age.

Comment: "Inspite of the answer I wrote, I'm also mildly in favor of 'Photography Chat' name. Not for us, but for the sake of outsiders and passers-by the name should be clear about what this place is. If it was only for ourselves I'd like 'The Darkroom' more." in chat, Oct.15th 2013 - 9:24 GMT

Comment: @Olin: I am curious how much that might actually affect our users, as I figure the vast majority of them who would be interested would be clicking on the chat link in the header anyway...which just says "chat".

Comment: ^-- and says _"All-things photography related discussion."_ in subheader under the name of the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference on "different" chat room names:

- The DMZ - Security SE
- The Bridge - Gaming SE
- Root Access - Super User SE
- The Litter Box - Pets SE
- The Comms Room - Server Fault SE
- The Upper Room - Christianity SE
- The Water Cooler - Workplace SE

For example "The Bridge" is not a chat room for a game of cards called Bridge.

Answer (score 0):

For the need of an answer to vote on, this one is in favor of

**The Darkroom**

Though "the darkroom" could be taken figuratively as a place to *develope ideas and techniques* with fellow photographers, it appears most people take the word darkroom literally as a room to have your film negatives enlargened and developed into paper prints, where lighting is a dim red light and a smell of chemicals fills the air. The Darkroom as a name of a chat room may be confusing.